# Word VBA, move the cursor to the beginning of the next number in a numbered list

Tags: vba, ms-word

Let's say I have a numbered list, where each number is followed by several bullet points: such as

1. Numbered List1.

- Bulleted List1
- Bulleted List2

2. Numbered List2

- Bulleted List3
- Bulleted List4

3. Numbered List3.

I want to be able to put my cursor at anywhere in "Numbered List1" and run the macro to put my cursor at the start of Numbered List2, skipping all Bulleted Lists inbetween

Here is what i have been able to do..

```
Sub MoveToNextNumberedListItem()
    ' This checks if cursor is in a numbered list
    If Selection.paragraphs(1).Range.ListParagraphs.count > 0 Then
        ' Moves cursor to end of that line
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine

        ' Moves the cursor to the beginning of the next list item
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    End If
End Sub
```

If i place my cursor anywhere in *Numbered List1* and run this, it only moves my cursor to *Bulleted List1* when i want it to go to the beginning of *Numbered List2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```vb
Sub MoveToNextNumberedListItem()
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Selection.Range

If rg.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start Then Exit Sub
If rg.ListParagraphs.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do
    Set rg = rg.ListParagraphs(1).Next.Range
Loop Until rg.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1

rg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rg.Select

End Sub
```

It looks for the next level 1 paragraph.